# Inject Type based on string parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, simple-injector

I would like to have the IoC create types based on parameters. I also need guidance on where to store this parameter info.

I need to make classes based on a string file type, more specific, based on extension.

I have a simple file info class for data:

```
class info
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to return classes based on that '`FileName`' extension so that I can render a viewer.

I'm using DataTemplates in WPF and assigning the type to the view works great.  I just need to assign the type based on the `FileName`.

Right now I'm just using a static array of extension strings `new[]{".pdf",".html",".jpg"};` to determine which type to return.  This is totally not sustainable.

I'd like to have a datasource that looked like this that:

```
Extension     Type
============= =============
.pdf          Webviewer
.html         Webviewer
.doc          Docviewer
.docx         Docviewer
.txt          Textviewer
```

ect.

Comment: I think this is case for factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which DI container you use. For instance, Simple Injector provides for ways to resolve dependencies based on a key: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key

Answer (score 2):

This is a grey area between a case statement, a database table, a factory pattern, and maybe IoC.  The correct solution is purely based on how mach different files you are dealing with.  Here is a little framework that can "act like" an Ioc container for you pruposes and allow you to define the extension => viewer mapping in a single location within your application.

Give your viewer's a commin interface or base class:

```
public interface IViewer {
    void LaunchViewer(string fileName);
}
```

Make your mapping class:

```
public class FileExtensionMap {
    private Dictionary<string, IViewer> maps;
    public IViewer this[string key] {
        get {
            if (!this.maps.ContainsKey(key)) {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            }

            return this.maps[key];
        }
    }

    public FileExtensionMap() {
        this.maps = new Dictionary<string, IViewer>();
        this.LoadMaps();
    }

    public void LoadMaps() {
        this.maps.Add("PDF", new PdfViewer());
        this.maps.Add("DOC", new WordViewer());
    }
}
```

Define your instance of the FileExtensionMap as a singleton or static class, whichever your prefer.

A short example.  You would either reference your static, your singleton, or pass the mapper as a dependency to your calling class:

```
public class Example {
    FileExtensionMap map;

    public Example(FileExtensionMap map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void View(FileInfo file) {
        map[file.Extension].LaunchViewer(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Updated mapping class that would instaniate a new instance for each call:

```
public class FileExtensionMap {
    private Dictionary<string, Func<IViewer>> maps;
    public IViewer this[string key] {
        get {
            if (!this.maps.ContainsKey(key)) {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            }

            return this.maps[key].Invoke();
        }
    }

    public FileExtensionMap() {
        this.maps = new Dictionary<string, Func<IViewer>>();
        this.LoadMaps();
    }

    public void LoadMaps() {
        this.maps.Add("PDF", () => new PdfViewer());
        this.maps.Add("DOC", () => new WordViewer());
    }
}
```

Comment: You design calls for just once instance of each viewer.  Typically we would want an instance of the viewer for each file.

Comment: Updated answer to create new instances of the viewer

Answer (score 0):

The Unity IoC allows registration of a type with a name.  The name could be the file extension.  I'm assuming that all viewers implement the `IViewer` interface.

```
// Register the viewer types
var viewers = new UnityContainer();
viewers
   .RegisterType<IViewer, Webwiewer>(".jpeg")
   .RegisterType<IViewer, Docviewer>(".doc");

// Get a viewer
var viewer = viewers.Resolve<IViewer>(ext);
```